# Twisted python - socket to bind to path on the filesystem

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to implement a socket server that receives rsyslog messages from windows or linux os. Ryslog uses omuxsock to output logs to socket server. I want to use twisted python to implement this socket that receives windows event/linux syslog messages. All the examples i've come across documentation only shows how to bind to IP and port. I want twisted socket to bind to a socket file not ip or port. eg., file "/var/syslog.sock"

in python without using twisted this can be done using:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind("/var/syslog.sock")
```

has anyone implemented socket in twisted python using socket file?

Answer (score 2):

With a reactor that supports `IReactorUNIX` you can do this either with the lower-level [listenUNIX](https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/stable/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorUNIX.html#listenUNIX) or the higher level [UNIXServerEndpoint](https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/stable/api/twisted.internet.endpoints.UNIXServerEndpoint.html).

For example

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.endpoints import UNIXServerEndpoint
from twisted.internet.protocols import Factory, Protocol

e = UNIXServerEndpoint(reactor, "/var/syslog.sock")
d = e.listen(Factory.forProtocol(Protocol))
reactor.run()
```